# How to trim specific text

Tags: postgresql, go

I have some text in file.Text like below:

```
#cat tmp 
host = "192.168.2.80"
port = 5432
user = "pnmsuser"
password = "PNMS$$$$$$"
dbname = "pnms"
```

Just I want text like below after trimming:

```
"192.168.2.80"
5432
"pnmsuser"
"PNMS$$$$$$"
"pnms"
```

I try to trim like below

```
func dbFileTrimming() {
    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("tmp")
    check(err)

    for key, line := range strings.Split(strings.TrimRight(string(dat), "\n"), "\n") {
        // println(key, line)
        if key == 3 {
            line := string([]rune(line)[11:])
            fmt.Println(line) 
        } else if key == 4 {
            line := string([]rune(line)[9:])
            fmt.Println(line)
        } else {
            line := string([]rune(line)[7:])
            fmt.Println(line)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a simple method for this?

Comment: It looks like you might want a YAML, INI, TOML, or some other format parser.

Comment: @Flimzy I will use this variable for connection db.This info is machine specific db info.I cannot use const variable for connection.

Comment: Use `bufio.Scanner` to iterate each line: skip comments beginning with`#`; split by space (assume values do not contain spaces?); verify middle split is `=`; last split is value.

Comment: I never said anything about using a contant. I suggested using a YAML, INI, or TOML parser, depending on the actual format of your config file.

Comment: Uppercase what? Are you reading my comments? Or just responding randomly? lol I really don't know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Chop the line after the `=`:

```
for _, line := range strings.Split(strings.TrimRight(string(dat), "\n"), "\n") {
     line = line[strings.Index(line, " = ")+3:]
     fmt.Println(line)
}
```

Comment: This might (or might not) work properly. It will choke on comments, or if there are more (or fewer) spaces than expected. Best would be to use a proper file parser.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an INI file, or similar enough so that libraries like [go-ini](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/ini.v1) could work.

Alternatively, try [Strings.split()](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) and putting the result in a map. Quick and dirty / untested:

```golang
result := map[string]string
for _, line := range strings.Split(string(dat), "\n") {
  split := strings.Split(line, "=")
  key := strings.Trim(split[0])
  value := strings.Trim(split[0])
  result[key] = value
}
```